# certbot HTTPS for same domain name but different port with two web server

Tags: lets-encrypt

I am trying to create a SSL with using certbot. 
Since I have one domain name is hosting the ip address with one port like www.example.com:510.

I am trying the same method to create a new ssl in another server and this server address was like www.example.com:509.

I cannot do that kind of things because of connection refused.
what do I missed or miss-understand the cert that I created.
I tried copy the same cert to other server but it cant

sorry for my poor english. pls let me know if you have any question of my question

Answer (score 4):

You do not need new certificate as the port is not a part of the certificate. Just add the same SSL config for both servers.